# Failure of tkinter .focus_set()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

The code below is part of a function that produces a simple dialog with caller selected text and buttons.

[image: Dialog with example text and four buttons: Save, save As, Don't save, Cancel]

The problem lies in the handling of key inputs of 's', 'a', 'd', and 'c. The code operates correctly for mouse clicks and tabbing followed by the space or enter keys. The code is written in Python 3.4 and is being tested for compliance with Windows 7.

My understanding is that Tk handles refocusing for the end user's mouse clicks. The space and enter keys are used after the user has changed focus by tabbing. For all of these interactions the keys are bound to each button by the code:

`for action in ('<1>', '<space>', '<Return>'):
     b.bind(action, handler)`

For 'underline' key input I believe my code needs to handle the refocusing prior to calling the handler. This is the purpose of the refocus routine. The print statement ("refocussing to...") is printed with the correct value for button.winfo_name() whenever 's', 'a', 's', or 'c' is pressed . This is why I believe `button.focus_set()` is failing.

If it worked this would enable the handler to simply check which button was pressed by looking at `event.widget.winfo_name()`. As it is, the failure to refocus means that the handler is called with the wrong button in `event.widget.winfo_name()`

If I move focus manually by tabbing then the focus gives the name returned by `event.widget.winfo_name()` regardless of which of 's', 'a', 'd', or 'c' is pressed.

After reading other posts on Stack Overflow, I tried adding `button.focus_force()` after `button.focus_set()`. This had no effect on the problem.

I have tried passing the button name by changing the signature of the handler to `def button_handler(event, *args)` and then changing the last line of `refocus` to handler(event, button.winfo_name()) but `*args` is empty when called.

```
def refocus_wrapper(button):
    def refocus(event):
        print("refocusing to '{}'".format(button.winfo_name()))
        button.focus_set()
        handler(event)
    return refocus

for button_text, underline, button_name in buttons:
    b = ttk.Button(button_inner_frame, text=button_text, name=button_name,
                   underline=underline)
    b.pack(padx=2, side='left')
    for action in ('<1>', '<space>', '<Return>'):
        b.bind(action, handler)
    action = '{}'.format(button_text[underline:underline + 1].lower())
    dialog.bind(action, refocus_wrapper(b))
    if not default or default == button_name:
        default = button_name
        b.focus_set()
```

Comment: Where's the code that is setting the bindings on the `a`, `c`, `d` and `s` keys?

Comment: @BryanOakley. `dialog.bind(action, refocus_wrapper)`. 
The button text is visible to end users so it comes from an external configuration file which can be easily internationalized. The underlined accelerator key is dependent on the language of the configuration file. Since I don't know what 'Cancel' looks like in Sanskrit, for example, nor which letter will be used as the accelerator key the underline is also in the external configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial assumption about needing to set the focus on the button is not correct. The usual method to handle this in Tk is to bind the accelerator key event on the dialog toplevel form and call the buttons invoke method for the event binding.

In Tcl/Tk thats:

```
toplevel .dlg
pack [button .dlg.b -text "Save" -underline 0 -command {puts "Save pressed"}]
bind .dlg <Alt-s> {.dlg.b invoke}
```

So bind the key events on whatever toplevel is the parent for your buttons. If that is a dialog then its parent should be the application toplevel widget.

A python equivalent is:

```
from tkinter import *
main = Tk()
dialog = Toplevel(main)
button = Button(dialog, text="Send", underline="0", command=lambda: print("hello"))
button.pack()
dialog.bind('<Alt-s>', lambda event: button.invoke())
main.mainloop()
```

The key binding appends an event object to the callback function which we can discard using a lambda  to wrap the call the the button's invoke method.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I have tried what I believe is Python's equivalent in `dialog.bind('<Alt-s>', b.invoke)`. This produces "TypeError:  invoke() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". 
I also tried the full pathname `dialog.children['button_outer_frame'].children[               'button_inner_frame'].children[str(button_name)].invoke` which produced the same error.  The code `dialog.button_outer_frame.button_inner_frame.b.invoke` will not run as `button_outer_frame` is not an attribute of dialog.

Comment: The invoke method takes no arguments but the key binding is automatically appending something. You can use a lambda to fix that. See the edit above.

Comment: The Type error has disappeared but the keys 's', 'a', 'd', and 'c' do nothing. I can't see how they would given that the callback function `handler` must be bound to the dialog. In my 'working' answer this happens indirectly via the call to `refocus`.

Comment: @lemi57ssss: it works because every widget has its toplevel parent as part of its bindtags. Roughly speaking, it "inherits" all bindings on the toplevel ("inherit" isn't literally what happens, but it's close enough for this discussion). If you bind `<Alt-s>` to the toplevel widget, the binding will fire no matter which widget in the dialog has the keyboard focus. You shouldn't have to do any refocusing at all.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: If I replace `dialog.bind(action, invoker_wrapper(b))` with `dialog.bind(action, lambda event: b.invoke())`, the accelerator keys all bind to the last button ('Cancel' in the example illustrated). So if the caller asks for a dialog with ten buttons all the accelerator keys are bound to button #10. This is because the lambda gets set to the values encountered during the last pass through the `for` loop (see my revised code below). I conclude that  lambda is only available in scenarios with predefined buttons.

Comment: @lemi57ssss: You can use lambda for ten buttons, you just need to use lambda correctly. There are several answers on this site related to that. You do _not_ need to set focus in these bindings, you _do_ need to properly define a binding for each special key except space and mouse click. The bindings can all be on the toplevel window because the buttons will "see" those bindings.

Comment: I've changed the line to `dialog.bind(action, lambda event, b=b: b.invoke())` and it works perfectly. It's an interesting construction which I was surprised to find explicitly mentioned in the Python FAQ documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`focus_set()` was, of course, working perfectly. My expectation that refocusing would rewrite the event object was at fault. The following code (which has been extensively revised to incorporate Brian Oakley's suggestions) produces the expected results.:

```
def _make_buttons(dialog, buttons, buttonbox, default, handler):
    def bcommand_wrapper(button):
        def bcommand():
            name = button.winfo_name()
            dialog.destroy()
            handler(name)
        return bcommand

    for button_text, underline, button_name in buttons:
        b = ttk.Button(buttonbox, text=button_text, underline=underline,
                       name=button_name)
        b.configure(command=bcommand_wrapper(b))
        b.pack(padx=2, side='left')
        action = button_text[underline:underline + 1].lower()
        try:
            dialog.bind(action, lambda event, b=b: b.invoke())
        except tk.TclError:
            raise ValueError(
                "Invalid underline of '{}' in position {}. Character '{}'.".
                format(button_text, underline, action))
        b.bind('<Return>', lambda event, b=b: b.invoke())
        if not default or default == button_name:
            default = button_name
            b.focus_set()
```

I gave up my original idea of returning a Tk event to the caller. This is a dialog so the caller isn't going to need anything more than the name of the button that was clicked.

Note that I am not trapping accelerator keys with the 'Alt' modifier. The 'Alt' key, at least on MS Windows, is a functional key when used with accelerator keys: It causes the display of underlines on menus. Here the underlines are static and so the use of the 'Alt' key would be inappropriate.

Comment: This is too complicated. You don't need to bind to `<1>`, etc. tkinter handles focus for you.

Comment: I can drop <1> and <space> but <Return> doesn't work without an explicit binding.

Comment: yes, you need to bind to `<Return>`. You don't have to make the binding set the focus, you just have to make it do the default behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Might I suggest using root.bind('c', ) to just have the shortcuts perform what you want?

Just make sure to only bind them when the window pops up, and unbind them when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The shortcuts are binding correctly. This is demonstrated by the print statement. I'm not clear on how rebinding them to a different widget would fix the focus problem.

Comment: @lemi57ssss Its because the root binding is a global one, which is why it is important to make sure that you bind it only when necessary, and unbind it when completed.

I won't lie, it is probably not the best method, however it is one that is both easy to implement and will work without fail until someone suggests a better solution, something which I unfortunately cannot provide.